# View close votes, reopen votes, and delete votes with insufficient repuation

Tags: script, javascript, closing, jquery

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

> [image]

### About

This script shows the number of current close votes, reopen votes and delete votes for a question. Works on all Stack Exchange sites.

#### License

GNU Lesser General Public License v3.0. Free.

#### Download

[Install userscript](https://gist.github.com/M-Daniil/ba0c2300db72bd7660128c9b339d8ab1/raw/2bf60715fe0f32796ad5d8d0d1dcc631a35786dd/retrieveCVRVDV.user.js).

#### Platform

Install using a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/).

### Contact

Contact [Xnero](https://stackapps.com/users/69047/Xnero) for any bugs/feedbacks.

### Code

Written using JavaScript, uses jQuery. Source code available [here](https://gist.github.com/M-Daniil/ba0c2300db72bd7660128c9b339d8ab1).