# Question close, reopen, and delete votes in the post sidebar

Tags: script, questions

### About

This is for users that cannot normally see these votes. On Stack Overflow that is less than 3,000 reputation points for close and reopen votes, and 10,000 reputation points for delete votes. The script will place them in the left sidebar under the timeline:

[image]

which makes the placement of the votes identical to the way [Answer delete votes in the post sidebar](https://stackapps.com/questions/9095/answer-delete-votes-in-the-post-sidebar) places delete votes in the left sidebar.

Like the other mentioned script, this will show the votes in reviews as well as on posts.

#### How it works

It uses the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) to fetch information about the Question, using [/questions/{ids}](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids).

The displayed "Quota" is the remaining total daily API requests. It's independent of individual user scripts. This means a user can request information from the API 10,000 times a day total. For more information see [Rate Limiting / Throttles](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).

#### Inspiration

The script was inspired by [this original userscript](https://gist.github.com/double-beep/3a300ebc521d60ed3d5a0c955023ff86) version 0.2, by [double-beep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10607772). A later version can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/double-beep/my-userscripts/blob/master/retrieveDVCV.user.js)

The script is simlar to:

- [View close votes, reopen votes, and delete votes with insufficient repuation](https://stackapps.com/questions/8671/view-close-votes-reopen-votes-and-delete-votes-with-insufficient-repuation) by [Xnero](https://stackapps.com/users/69047)
- [View close/reopen votes without 3k rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/9117/view-close-reopen-votes-without-3k-rep) by [Spectric](https://stackapps.com/users/76056)

#### Sites

Across the Stack Exchange network.

#### Platform

Should work with any user script manager in any major browser.
Tested with [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) using [Opera](https://www.opera.com/).

#### Download

[GitHub](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/tree/main/StackRetrieveQuestionCloseReopenDeleteVotes) | [Install](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/raw/main/StackRetrieveQuestionCloseReopenDeleteVotes/StackRetrieveCloseReopenDeleteVotes.user.js)

### Contact

For bugs, please post here. Comments are fine too.